# Write to Binary files in Java

Tags: java, binary

I am trying to write a lot of data into a binary file. Because it is a lot of data, it is important that this is done fast and I want to be able to write the data as ints one by one. I have tried `RandomAccessFile`, `BufferedWriter`, `DataOutputStream` etc. but all of those are either too slow or cannot write ints. Any ideas that might help me?

Comment: Get a faster hard drive ;-)  - seriously, how do you know the bottleneck is on the Java side? If the disk is slow, there is nothing Java can do ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every stream can 'write ints' if you write the correct code to convert ints to bytes.

The two 'fast' IO options in Java are `BufferedOutputStream` on top of `FileOutputStream` and the use of a `FileChannel` with NIO buffers.

If all you are writing is many, many, `int` values, you can use `IntBuffer` instances to pass the data to a `fileChannel`.

Further, 'one at a time' is generally incompatible with 'fast'. Sooner or later, data has to travel to the disk in blocks. If you force data to disk in small quantities, you will find that the process is very slow. You could, for example, add integer values to a buffer and write the buffer when it fills, and then repeat.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried BufferedOutPutstream together with FileOutPutStream, but didn't get how to use intbuffer. I need to look further into it!

Comment: You might want to get your shift key looked at. It seems to have a mind of its own.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `java.nio` package. You will find classes that you can use for your needed purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, writing to a file one int at a time isn't an inherently fast operation. Even with bufferedwriter you're potentially making a lot of function calls (and may still be doing a lot of file writes if you haven't set the buffer to be large enough).

Have you tried putting the integers into an array, using ByteBuffer to convert it to a byte array, and then writing the byte array to a file?